# How can I match a reStructuredText code block with Regex and Python?

Tags: python, regex, restructuredtext

I am trying to extract a `code block` from a `.rst` document using *Python* and *regex*. The code blocks in the document are defined by adding a `.. code-block:: python` directive to the text and then indenting by a few spaces.

Here is an example from my test document:

```
.. code-block:: python

  import os
  from selenium import webdriver
  from axe_selenium_python import Axe

  def test_google():
      driver = webdriver.Firefox()
      driver.get("http://www.google.com")
      axe = Axe(driver)
      # Inject axe-core javascript into page.
      axe.inject()
      # Run axe accessibility checks.
      results = axe.execute()
      # Write results to file
      axe.write_results(results, 'a11y.json')
      driver.close()
      # Assert no violations are found
      assert len(results["violations"]) == 0,    axe.report(results["violations"])
      driver.close()
```

So far I have this regex:
`(\.\. code-block:: python\s\s)(.*\s.+).*?\n\s+(.*\s.+)+`

The problem with this pattern is that it selects only the first part and last part of the test string. I need help in writing a pattern that can capture *everything* within the `.. code-block:: python` code block excluding the `..code-block:: python` directive.

You can see the progress I have made with this [here](https://regex101.com/r/9UKjys/1).

Comment: You should use a restructedtext parser.

Comment: Suggest instead putting the content of the code-block into an external file, then use [`literalinclude`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-literalinclude) to display it in the .rst file and do whatever you intend to do with the regex with the source file.

Comment: @KlausD. Do you have any recommendations on which parsers I can look into?

Comment: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2017/a-brief-tutorial-on-parsing-restructuredtext-rest/

Comment: Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on using regex, the following should do the trick, given provided example:

```
import re

pattern = r"(\.\. code-block:: python\s+$)((\n +.*|\s)+)"

matches = re.finditer(pattern, text, re.M)

for m, match in enumerate(matches):
    for g, group_text in enumerate(match.groups()):
        print("###match {}, group {}:###".format(m, g))
        print(group_text, end="")
```

The trick, I believe, is to use nested parenthesis and the MULTILINE or M flag.

The resulting `match` object(s) will have 3 [groups](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects), as defined by the parenthesis:

- group 1: the '.. code-block:' header
- group 2: the contents of the code block
- group 3: an empty group as a result of the extra grouping parenthesis.

To retrieve group `n`, use `match.group(n)`. Note that indexing of groups starts at `1` and passing `0` or no arguments will result in the entire matching string.

Comment: Thank you for this! It works. Is there a way to select the same text and *not* include the `code-block:: python` directive in the match object?